# Initializing google map depending on form results

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps

So I have a form with just a select field. Depending on what the user selected markers will get rendered through AJAX on the map. The thing is how to initialize the function and create the map.

I just found that people are doing it this way:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

So the map is initialized when a full page reload finishes. What I need is to call the initialize function and create the map when an ajax request is done performing. How can one achieve this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several ways on doing that. you can set a promise, or a listener to your AJAX, but the simplest way to do that is just call `initialize()` at the end of your AJAX code.

Since `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` basically has the same effect with `<body onload="initialize()">`, or `$( document ).ready(initialize())`, so you should be able to call the `initialize()` whenever you want.

Comment: Pretty straightforward :) Thanks!